# Android - I'm trying to make Onclick Event and while the app start it give me this Error

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that change some text in main activity but this is not the error. The real error in OnClick Event it says:

> Incompatible Types

and here is the two files that contains the error

first_.xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".First_Activ" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:title="AlMA PRO Leader - First Test"
    android:id="@+id/AlmaSettingItem"
    android:onClick="Doit"
    />
</menu>
```

First_Activ.java is :

```
@Override
public Void DoIt(MenuItem Item){
    TextView txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ARMY );
    txt.setText("Done");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Error is in First_Activ.java

```
 @Override
public Void DoIt(MenuItem Item){
    TextView txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ARMY );
    txt.setText("Done");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How is declared R.id.ARMY?

Comment: the hole error is in [return true;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it declared in your xml as

```
android:onClick="Doit"
```

but in Java you have

```
public Void DoIt(MenuItem Item){
```

"Doit" isn't the same case in both. Fix that. If that isn't your problem then please post the errors.

So change in your xml

```
android:onClick="doIt"
```

Also, remove the `return` statement in your function and the return type to `void` and change the function name so it sticks to Java standards.

```
@Override
public void doIt(MenuItem item){
    TextView txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ARMY );
    txt.setText("Done");
}
```

I also changed `Item` to `item` to stick with Java standards

Comment: Incompatible Types.
Required : Java.lang.Void
Found : Boolean

Comment: @OmarAlMA3lOl combine my answer with that of Loco (including his initial comment) and it should work

Comment: thank you i done that but how to make it return Void ??

Comment: You don't return Void. You use void to say you aren't returning anything. And see Loco's other answer. You really need to learn Java basics before tackling Android.

Comment: You Have HELPED ME THANK YOU SO MUCH ^^

Comment: @OmarAlMA3lOl you are welcome. You can only accept one answer. I see the tick mark going back and forth but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This code can't be compiled. You are trying to return something. But what your

```
public Void DoIt(MenuItem Item)
```

is actually returning?

Omar, I think you don't know the main principles of Java. I suggest you to read Java basics and Android. Writing the code and asking the help here without understanding what this code is actually suppose to do is not the solution.

Comment: It's total mess. Void must be void.

Comment: when i remove [Return true;]
it give me Missing Return Statement

Comment: @Loco you should add that in your answer and if you want to add mine you can and I will delete it. But that's up to you. I think that should fix all the issues I see

Comment: I didn't understand what should I do.

Comment: It's your answer so you *should* do with it *whatever you want*. But if you add your first comment into the answer and edit my answer into it then I think it will be a complete answer and fix the problems.

Comment: I Edited My Code into this:
@Override
    public Void  DoIt(MenuItem Item){
        TextView txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ARMY );
        txt.setText("Done");
        return DoIt(Item);
    }
But gives me another error 

Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: @Loco I went ahead and did it in my answer since you didn't understand what I meant but I was saying it was ok to combine it all into one answer and I would delete mine so there was one solid answer. Since both answers had information that would fix the problems.

Comment: absolutely savage